# Adding a value to a repeating element in my BizTalk Orchestration Message Assignment

Tags: vb.net, biztalk

I’m having trouble adding a value to a repeating element in my BizTalk Orchestration Message Assignment component. Here is what I have done.  I created a VB.net class with the XSD.exe tool for my schema. I also create a VB.net helper class that inherits my schema class and added that class as a variable to my orchestration.  I am trying to create a new message within the assignment component. When setting values to non-repeating element it is working and the message is created. But I’m not sure how to set a value to a repeating element. When I try with the code below a will get an error “Inner exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.”.  The error is on this line “CredentialsLookupRequestHeader.IDs[0] = CategoryValueType;”.  CategoryValueType is a complex type and can have more than one.

-Helper Class

```
<Serializable>
<XmlRoot("CredentialsLookupAdapterType")> _
Public Class CredentialsLookupAdapterType
    Inherits CredentialsLookupRequestV1_3Type

    Public Function ToXmlDocument() As XmlDocument
        Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(CredentialsLookupAdapterType), New Type() {GetType(CredentialsLookupRequestV1_3Type)})
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        serializer.Serialize(New StringWriter(sb, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), Me)

        Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
        doc.LoadXml(sb.ToString)
        Return doc
    End Function
End Class
```

Assignment component in biztalk

```
//Create new request message
CredentialsLookupRequest = new CredentialsLookupRequest_V1_3.CredentialsLookupAdapterType();

//Create header
CredentialsLookupRequestHeader = new CredentialsLookupRequest_V1_3.OLMHeaderType();

//Header values
CredentialsLookupRequestHeader.RequestCategory = "RETRIEVE";
CredentialsLookupRequestHeader.SubmittingEntityName = "BizTalk";

//Header IDs
CategoryValueType = new CredentialsLookupRequest_V1_3.CategoryValueType();
CategoryValueType.Category = "BizTalk Orchestration ID";
CategoryValueType.Value = "BZ000001";
CredentialsLookupRequestHeader.IDs[0] = CategoryValueType;
CredentialsLookupRequestHeader.MessageCategory = "confidential";

CredentialsLookupRequest.Header = CredentialsLookupRequestHeader;

msgRequest = CredentialsLookupRequest.ToXmlDocument();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use xpath to assign a value.. no need to use helper function.

Comment: I know that I could use xpath. I could also use LoadXml or a map. But for this project I needed/wanted to do it this way. But thank you reply I very well may end up using xpath.